# Identity Server 4 .Net Core 2.0: Multiple authentication type

Tags: oauth, asp.net-core, identityserver4

Is this on point?

[Multiple authenticaiton schemes in asp.net core 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46691485/multiple-authenticaion-schemes-in-asp-net-core-2-0)

I would like to have multiple types of authentication in my .netcore project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

You will need to make sure you set the authentication scheme correctly in the ConfigureServices.

```
services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddCookie("MyCookieAuthenticationScheme", options => {

        })
        .AddAnotherHandler("AnotherName", options => { });
```

Then for each controller/action, you will need to specify the eligible schemes

Example:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Scheme1")]
public IActionResult Test1() { }


[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Scheme2")]
public IActionResult Test2() { }


[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Scheme1,Scheme2")]
public IActionResult Test3() { }
```

You can also create your own Authentication Handler if needed.

Good luck,
Seb